# Find file on usb

Tags: android, usb-drive

I'm trying to check if a certain file exists on a plugged usb-stick. This is the code:

```
File usb_dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(usb_dir+ "/update.apk");

if (myFile.exists()==true) {
    final Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///mnt/usb_storage/update.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(promptInstall);

    } else if (myFile.exists()==false){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not working!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

everything works fine instead of myFile.exists. no matter what I do it returns false. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 String usb_dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 File myFile = new File(usb_dir+ "/update.apk");
```